# How can I get/print value from row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I have problem with get item from row. In finally version columns can be really more so I need code who if i press in row/cell and click button show me values/text in any cells in row

I tried do something with currentRow but I don't understand how this work

```
def Table(self):
self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

BtnShow = QPushButton("&Show row values", self)
BtnShow.setFixedSize(40,30)
BtnShow.clicked.connect(self.on_click)
#If I press this button, I want to show me all values in any cell in row 

    self.tableWidget = QTableWidget()
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(2)
    self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(3)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(0,0, QTableWidgetItem("One"))
    self.tableWidget.setItem(0,1, QTableWidgetItem("Two"))
    self.tableWidget.setItem(0,2, QTableWidgetItem("Three"))
    self.tableWidget.setItem(1,0, QTableWidgetItem("val_scan.scan_a()"))
    self.tableWidget.setItem(1,1, QTableWidgetItem("val_scan.scan_b()"))
    self.tableWidget.setItem(1,2, QTableWidgetItem("val_scan.scan_c()"))
    self.tableWidget.move(0,0)
    self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
    self.layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
    self.setLayout(self.layout)

    #self.tableWidget.clicked.connect(self.on_click)

    self.resize(640, 480)
    self.move(300, 300)
    self.setWindowTitle('Table')
    self.show()

def on_click(self):
    #Can I do get_Item from self.tableWidget or something?
```

Thanks for answers :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **QTableWidget.selectedItems()**
>
> Returns a list of all selected items.
>
> This function returns a list of pointers to the contents of the
>   selected cells.To get text of selected item use `.text()`

```
def on_click(self):
    item = self.tableWidget.selectedItems()
    print (item[0].text())
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry for not respond I was in journey :-)

Comment: No worries ;) im glad tgat I helped